# Detecting when a microphone is unplugged

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have a Windows Forms application and in this I have a <kbd>Start</kbd> and a <kbd>Stop</kbd> button. When I click the <kbd>Start</kbd> button a recording should start and when I click the <kbd>Stop</kbd> button the recording should stop. It's working fine, but my requirement is when I started recording, if I unplug the microphone the recording should stop. However, my current code does not do this. Here is my current code:

```
uint hr = MFRecWrapper.StartRecording(microPhoneName.Trim(), this.fileName.Trim(), this.bitSamplingBitrate, this.avgBytesWrittenPerSecond, this.Handle);
uint hr = MFRecWrapper.StopRecording();
```

How can I make it so that it achieves that effect? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you will have to do it through unmanaged code and hook to windows event.  [WM_DEVICECHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363480%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Example

```
   using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    const int WM_DEVICECHANGE = 0x0219;
     // new device is pluggedin
     const int DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL = 0x8000; 
     //device is removed 
    const int DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE = 0x8004; 
     //device is changed
    const int DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED = 0x0007; 
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_DEVICECHANGE
         {
              //Your code here.
         }
       base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Comment: what is 0x0219?? should i hardcode this value?? iam new to this windows procedure can you please solve my problem by giving the all code...thannk you for your concern

Comment: yes hardcode this value. See the link i have given to read the details.

Comment: @sree glad it helped you. By the way take a look at other constants as well. They might be useful to you as well.

Comment: @EhsanUllah i need one more help from you,now i want to stop recording when no one speaks. is it possible?

Comment: or post another question, someone might be able to help you.

Comment: @EhsanUllah: Hi, the above code worked perfectly for me in my system, recently i tested it in another system, the wndProc is not calling when i unplugged my microphone, I am uanble to rectify where I am going wrong, Can you Please suggest me where could be the problem,Thank you

Comment: Is there a change flag when user is using a microphone to record or call in the pc?

Answer (score 0):

i quote:
In unmanaged code you would listen for [WM_DEVICECHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363480%28VS.85%29.aspx) in your top level windowproc.

That appears to be the only way to do it in managed code as well.