# How to check if a microphone is available for recording

Tags: c#, wpf, audio, microphone

I am working on a WPF application where In need to record audio messages from my user. I followed code on [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/NET-Voice-Recorder) and its working fine. Now the problem is if it is a desktop I am only checking if there is a built in microphone but not if there is any external microphone connected or not. And I also want to know if the user has disabled the microphone. Can you tell me how to check if any external microphone is connected. I need to display a error message if user will not be able to record audio.

Comment: The list of waveInDevices includes all connected microphones. There is no difference between external microphones or built in microphones.

Comment: @thefiloe are u saying there is no way to find out if any external microphone is connected?

Comment: Well, you may could try to use MMDevices (Wasapi). Wasapi provides more details about devices (take a look at the PropertyStore of IMMdevice). But if you really want to use the obsolete waveIn APIs, I am afraid of that there is no wait to find out whether it is an external device or not.

Comment: It would depend upon the sound card and it's driver that supports detection or not.

Answer (score 1):

In order to detect changes in hardware in C#, you can use the [`WM_DEVICECHANGE` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363480%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which *Notifies an application of a change to the hardware configuration of a device or the computer*.

As I am far from an expert in this area, I'd rather point you towards the [Detecting when a microphone is unplugged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669326/detecting-when-a-microphone-is-unplugged) question here on StackOverflow, rather than try to explain it to you. The accepted answer from that post should help you with detecting when a microphone has been unplugged. From the accepted answer to the linked question:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
const int WM_DEVICECHANGE = 0x0219;
// new device is pluggedin
const int DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL = 0x8000; 
//device is removed 
const int DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE = 0x8004; 
//device is changed
const int DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED = 0x0007; 
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_DEVICECHANGE
    {
        //Your code here.
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Here are some further links that may help you with your project:

> [Sound Activated Recorder with Spectrogram in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22951/Sound-Activated-Recorder-with-Spectrogram-in-C) from CodeProject
>   [.NET Voice Recorder](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/NET-Voice-Recorder) from Channel 9
>   [.NET Voice Recorder](http://voicerecorder.codeplex.com/) from CodePlex

Comment: Is there a way to check if the device is recording using a microphone?

Comment: @Ali123 I'm also looking for the same thing, did you find something?