# Referencing the System.Speech.Recognition library - C#

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, microphone, sapi

I have a problem with my speech recognition reference in my C# application. When I reference it in my C# code with the `using System.Speech.Recognition` statement, the program will only run when a microphone is present and will refuse to run when the opposite case is true. Is there a way that I can use this library selectively, so that the program won't shut down if another computer that is hosting it doesn't have a microphone? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Rather than an interpretation of what you think the error is, the exact text of the errors you are seeing would be more helpful

Comment: show some code where you trying to use the reference

Comment: Your question is actually "How to detect if a microphone is present" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669326/detecting-when-a-microphone-is-unplugged or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff827802.aspx

Comment: It's not an error with the debugger. When I run it (outside the debugger) on a machine without a microphone, I receive a system error dialog: **"No audio input device found. Make sure your audio hardware is working properly and check your audio configuration in the Audio Devices and Sound Themes control panel."**

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for the presence of the microphone before you create the SpeechRecognizer object.

I.e., instead of doing:

```
using System.Speech.Recognition;

SpeechRecognizer reco = new SpeechRecognizer();
```

do

```
using System.Speech.Recognition;

SpeechRecognizer reco = null;

if (MicrophonePresent())
{
    reco = new SpeechRecognizer();
    // do remainder of setup here
}
```